# Gmail website priority inbox: unread; remaining inbox; starred; drafts

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail, priority-inbox

I wonder whether there is a way to customize the Gmail priority inbox on the gmail website as:

1. Unread inbox
2. Remaining inbox
3. Starred
4. Drafts

The settings let me do the order 1-3-4-2 (where 2 is "everything else"), but I'd prefer the above.

> Are there tweaks that make this ordering possible?

Answer (score 2):

One approach for this is to use Multiple inboxes. They could be

- label:inbox is:unread
- label:inbox is:read
- is:starred
- is:drafts

Then set "Extra panels positioning" to above the inbox.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But only with a few (minor) drawbacks: First, I still have another section on the bottom with my usual inbox that I would prefer to not see a second time on the page. Second, empty sections do not disappear when empty as they used to do. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In fact, it would be great if I could combine priority inbox (with two sections inbox unread and inbox read) and multiple inboxes (with two sections starred and drafts). But the multiple inboxes seem to only work with the classical inbox... Do you know how to do that?